# Can I install emacs 24.5 on OS X El Capitan without deleting the native OS X emacs?

Tags: macos, emacs, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

I want to install the latest version of emacs, but if I do this will it be in conflict with the version that comes pre-packaged with os x? Do I need to delete the native emacs? Also, it seems emacsforosx.com is a popular option, but I lot of people swear by homebrew... why would I go with one option over the other?

Comment: I would think that System Integrity Protection would mean you cannot remove the Apple-provided emacs (`/usr/bin/emacs`). I don't use emacs, but Homebrew will install to `/usr/local/`, which should be earlier in your path than `/usr/bin/`.

Comment: The last part of your question isn't really acceptable on Stack Overflow, as [software recommendations are explicitly listed as off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Anyway, you should only post one question per ... question.

Comment: Just download the `dmg` and drag the `app` to your applications folder:  http://emacsformacosx.com/  You don't really need homebrew or macports, though those are certainly acceptable alternatives.  The aforementioned link also has an option for other version, which will take you to a section for nightly builds of Emacs 25 if that interests you.  See also:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/what-is-the-difference-between-aquamacs-and-other-mac-versions-of-emacs

Comment: @lawlist Homebrew/MacPorts will provide you automatic updates; I don’t think the `dmg` does.

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason to remove the system-supplied Emacs; any well-behaved, properly packaged third-party version will install fine alongside, not over, the system binaries and libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Installing a current version of emacs is normal practice because the OSX provided version is outdated. You have a number of options, but I've found using the 'homebrew' method the easiest.

Due to changes in OSX 10.11, you need to take some additional steps when installing homebrew. If you already have homebrew installed, you will probably need to 'fix' the permissions on /usr/local. If you don't have homebrew installed, then there are some additional steps you will need to take to create the /usr/local path. This is documented on the hombrew site at [El Capitan and Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/El_Capitan_and_Homebrew.md)